# Dll missing error from java\jdk\bin folder while executing SSIS package

Tags: java, sql-server, ssis

I have created a simple SSIS package which brings in data from SQL Server and Oracle databases into staging table and dumps it into a SQL Server target table after processing. although all the transformation are getting executed successfully, at the end getting the below error message.

```
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  03:16:33
Finished: 04:44:48
Elapsed:  5294.77 seconds
found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll D:\Program_Files\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e
```

similarly for one more SSIS package the same issue persist, but getting errors for bunch of dll's.

```
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  18:40:31
Finished: 20:50:27
Elapsed:  7795.84 seconds
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\system\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\WAAE_PRD\autosys\bin\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Perl64\site\bin\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Perl64\bin\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\WAAE_PRD\autosys\bin\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\NCR\Common Files\Shared ICU Libraries for Teradata\lib\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\NCR\Teradata Client\cliv2\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll c:\apps\oracle\client32\11.2.0.3\home1\bin\oci.dll found 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\system\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\WAAE_PRD\autosys\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Perl64\site\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Perl64\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\WAAE_PRD\autosys\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\NCR\Common Files\Shared ICU Libraries for Teradata\lib\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\NCR\Teradata Client\cliv2\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll c:\apps\oracle\client32\11.2.0.3\home1\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll c:\apps\oracle\client64\11.2.0.3\home1\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Apps\Sybase15\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\HP\NCU\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\system32\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Apps\Sybase\Bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Apps\Sybase\DLL\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Scripts\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll c:\opscode\chef\bin\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e 
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files\ibm\tivoli\tsm\baclient\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e
```

Has anybody encountered this issue before ? Any pointer would be of great help.